# Menu appearing on mobile view in desktop browsers but not on actual mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a site using wordpress. I'm making a custom menu. When you activate `mobile view` in inspect element it works fine, but from an actual phone the menu seems to be transparent (it opens but you don't notice, press top right to activate the invisible close button). I've tried adding the z-index. It is position fixed, but still nothing is working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  var $ = jQuery;

  $(".mobile_menu_button").click(function(e){
    $(".mobile_menu li").css("margin-top","20px");
    $(".mobile_menu").fadeIn();
    $(".mobile_menu li").animate({marginTop: "0"}, 500);
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".mobile_menu ul").fadeIn();
  });

  $(".mobile_menu i").click(function(e){
    closeMenu();
  });
});

function closeMenu()
{
  var $ = jQuery;
  $(".mobile_menu li").animate({marginTop: "20px"}, 500);
  $(".mobile_menu").fadeOut();
}
```

And Here  is the CSS:

```
.mobile_menu ul{
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    padding-top: 6% !important;
    background: white !important; 
}
```

And Here is a the wordpress html/php code :

```
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li class = "close"> <i class = "fa fa-times" onclick = "closeMenu()"></i> </li>';
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'left-top-navigation' ,
  'container'  => '',
  'container_class' => '',
  'menu_class' => '',
  'menu_id' => '',
  'fallback_cb' => '',
  'link_before' => '<span>',
  'link_after' => '</span>',
  'walker' => new qode_type4_walker_nav_menu(),
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s'
));
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'right-top-navigation' ,
  'container'  => '',
  'container_class' => '',
  'menu_class' => '',
  'menu_id' => '',
  'fallback_cb' => '',
  'link_before' => '<span>',
  'link_after' => '</span>',
  'walker' => new qode_type4_walker_nav_menu(),
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s'
));
echo '</ul>';
```

Here is the link if you wish to test: https://cloudypro.net/demo/nfbynour/

Comment: _“it is position fixed”_ - looks like it isn’t, when I debug this (using BrowserStack), the `ul` element actually has `position:relative`, coming from a rule with the selector `nav.mobile_menu, nav.mobile_menu ul` (from `stylesheet.min.css` out of the `stockholm` theme folder.) For some reason the `!important` form your own stylesheet rule doesn’t seem to work, the first rule overwrites this. Try using a selector with the same specificity for your rule (`nav.mobile_menu ul`) and see if that changes things.

Comment: @misorude Thank you but it did not seem to work - problem is i cant debug on phone and pc browsers are working. I want to avoid using a paid solution like subscribing to browser stack. Can you please re check if its still being given relative ?

Comment: Nah, sorry, can’t keep checking on the issue for you repeatedly. BrowserStack offers a free trial, it limits the time you can test to five minutes or something like that. Alternatively, hook your phone up to your computer via USB, then you can remote-debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged this for you on iphone X, using Safari and it looks like nav.mobile_menu has an overflow: hidden on it. Because this technically doesn't have any height because the ul is position fixed its not showing you anything. Remove that overflow: hidden and your nav pops right up. [image]

Comment: YOU ARE A SAINT. Long live the KING OF THE NORTH