# Why does my mobile menu on this site work on browser but not on actual mobile device?

Tags: html, wordpress, sass, zurb-foundation

My mobile menu works fine on desktop browser but not actual mobile devices. I have tested it on Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

I have already tried [Menu appearing on mobile view in desktop browsers but not on actual mobiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299065/menu-appearing-on-mobile-view-in-desktop-browsers-but-not-on-actual-mobiles) but that does not seem to be the same case here.

```
    <div id="mobileSticky">
        <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="site-navigation">
            <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="mobile-menu"></button>
            <div class="title-bar-title">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" rel="home"><img src="/wp-content/themes/imagineItStudios2017/assets/images/header/logo.svg" alt="Imagine It Studios" class="desktopLogo"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I expect the menu to open on small desktop screens AND mobile devices as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the console log and found that there is a javascript error. I believe that's the cause.

After checking the code, I think it's from some kind of contact form plugin. And as the js file was minified and cached, I believe you are using some kind of cacing/minifying plugin on the site which sometimes causes issues with javascript.

Please check the javascript code carefully and modify the settings of the caching plugin(if there's any). I think the issue might get resolved.

[image: Console log][image: Prettified Code]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the class and see if that fixes it. Need to see the css but that or the mobile menu flag is breaking it. Otherwise it's trivial js.

Also, the rest of your class may have problems, try isolating the problem.

Comment: Removing the classes did not work. One of the problems I'm having troubleshooting is that it works on desktop but not on a mobile device. So it's hard to pinpoint.